# How do I find the final pose matrix for every bone to send to the shader?

Tags: armature, opengl

Hello any advice would really be appreciated.  I know there are lots of threads on this already but I have read many of them and I am still having trouble.  I want to export a simple skeletal animation to a JSON file and play it in opengl.  I am having trouble finding or calculating the correct matrix for each bone to send into the vertex shader.

I know this has been asked before but I have read a lot of threads and I am still having trouble with this.  How do I get the final matrix for every bone to send to the vertex shader?  What data do I need from blender for this?

I have tried using just the pose bone's matrix world, its parent's matrix_local times the pose bone's matrix_basis, many things but I always get a distorted model.

I'm pretty sure my vertices' bone weights and ids are working properly.  This is my vertex shader (which is working) I think I'm just sending the wrong bone transforms

This is my vertex shader (it won't let me paste code)
https://github.com/charmanderstrom/SkinnedVertexShader/blob/master/vertex_shader.glsl

Comment: As far as I know, vertex shaders require the matrix that transform the bone from *rest pose* to the *animated pose*, in **model space** coordinate system. Now, how to get that, no idea...

Comment: My take is `pose_bone.matrix @ pose_bone.bone.matrix_local.inverted()`, but I can't test it.